# Tables and bins from two vectors in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, vector

As an exercise I was given two samples from a seed called u and v and asked to show how many values are in `v` but not in `u` fell into the bins [1,50] and [51,100]. Then I am asked to  add a line of code in to confirm my answer using a relational operator (like >) and `sum()`.

I solved the first part:

```
table(findInterval(setdiff(v,u),c(50))
```

But for the second part, i don't really get what I need to do; any help is appreciated!

Example:

```
set.seed(1201)
u = sample(100,100,replace=TRUE)
v = sample(100,100,replace=TRUE)
```

```
table(findInterval(setdiff(v,u),c(50)))
```

Output:

```
0  1 
12 12
```

Comment: please see edits

Comment: So you want an answer with `>` and `sum`?

Comment: Perhaps `sum(findInterval(setdiff(v,u),c(50)) > 0)`

Comment: it just returns 12, canyou explain the meaning of the output and what you did? thanks

Comment: By using `setdiff`, the return vector will be unique i.e. if there are duplicates, it will be dropped.  Is that what you wanted? i.e. if you do `%in%` with `!`, it returns a different value `table(findInterval(v[!v %in% u], 50))`

Comment: May be you just need `i1 <- v[!v %in% u]  > 50; sum(i1); sum(!i1)`

Answer (score 0):

If we want to use comparative operators and `sum`, create a logical vector and get the `sum` of logical vector

```
i1 <- v[!v %in% u]  > 50
sum(i1)
sum(!i1)
```

Note:  If the OP intended to use only `unique` values (as in `setdiff`), then get the `unique`

```
i1 <- unique(v[!v %in% u]) > 50
out1 <- sum(i1)
out2 <- sum(!i1)
```

-checking with the output of `table`

```
tbl1 <- table(findInterval(setdiff(v,u),c(50)))
all.equal(as.numeric(tbl1), c(out1, out2), check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is only one number that you are cutting the intervals in, you can verify your answer using `>` directly.

This is your code

```
set.seed(1201)
u = sample(100,100,replace=TRUE)
v = sample(100,100,replace=TRUE)
table(findInterval(setdiff(v,u),50))

#0 1 
#9 9
```

Without `findInterval`

```
table(setdiff(v,u) > 50)

#FALSE  TRUE 
#    9     9
```